# Pine script coding

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to close out all positions at 1300 hours Pacific time. This is what I tried.  What do I need to change?

```
isOnePM = currentHour == desiredHour
// Exit all positions if it's 1:00 PM  
if (isOnePM)    
    strategy.close("ExitAll")
```

Comment: This is what I have found :      currentHour = hour(time, syminfo.timezone)                             if currentHour >= 16     strategy.close_all(comment = 'Trading session ended, all positions closed.')

Comment: Please see [MCVE] -- we need to know more information. How does your outcome differ from your desired outcome? Do you get an error?